# How to retrieve the result of Pregel ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb

I am a newbie and using ArangoDB 3.2.5. I would like to retrieve the result of pregel in ArangoDB. Here is a simple example in arangosh.

```
var pregel = require("@arangodb/pregel");
var params = {source: "Country/Tunesia"};
var execution = pregel.start("sssp", "CountryGraph", params);
```

In the document, it dumps the result of pregel in a field in the collection. Is there an alternative way like the following code to retrieve the result? I look for it in the document but didn't find it. By the way, you can load the dataset example used by the above code by loading [this](https://www.arangodb.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/createGraph.js). Thanks.

```
var result = pregel.getResult(execution);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result can not be returned directly. You have two options however:

- Let ArangoDB write the Pregel result into the documents
- Don't store the result, but only hold it temporarily in memory

To avoid persisting the result, there is an [option `store`](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Graphs/Pregel/#available-algorithms) which you have to set to `false.` You can [access the volatile result with AQL](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Graphs/Pregel/#aql-integration) through the function `PREGEL_RESULT(<handle>)`.

The flow is like this:

1. Start Pregel execution
2. Check status and wait until it changes to "done" or "canceled"
3. Perform an AQL query to access the result if Pregel succeeded

```
var pregel = require("@arangodb/pregel");
var params = {source: "Country/Algeria", store: false};
var handle = pregel.start("sssp", "CountryGraph", params);

while (!["done", "canceled"].includes(pregel.status(handle).state)) {
  print("waiting for result");
  require("internal").wait(0.5); // TODO: make this more clever
}

var status = pregel.status(handle);
print(status);

if (status.state == "done") {
  var query = db._query("FOR doc IN PREGEL_RESULT(@handle) RETURN doc", {handle: handle});
  print(query.toArray());
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
shell>arangosh --javascript.execute pregel.js

waiting for result

{
  "state" : "done",
  "gss" : 2,
  "totalRuntime" : 0.00583648681640625,
  "aggregators" : {
  },
  "sendCount" : 1,
  "receivedCount" : 1,
  "vertexCount" : 10,
  "edgeCount" : 8,
  "code" : 200
}

[
  {
    "_key" : "Germany",
    "result" : 9223372036854776000
  },
  {
    "_key" : "Switzerland",
    "result" : 9223372036854776000
  },
  {
    "_key" : "Brasil",
    "result" : 9223372036854776000
  },
  {
    "_key" : "Marocco",
    "result" : 9223372036854776000
  },
  {
    "_key" : "Argentina",
    "result" : 9223372036854776000
  },
  {
    "_key" : "Austria",
    "result" : 9223372036854776000
  },
  {
    "_key" : "Algeria",
    "result" : 0
  },
  {
    "_key" : "Uruguay",
    "result" : 9223372036854776000
  },
  {
    "_key" : "Tunesia",
    "result" : 1
  },
  {
    "_key" : "Australia",
    "result" : 9223372036854776000
  }
]
```